# Trying to .dup an activerecord entry, getting "undefined method `stringify_keys' "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using [Deep clonable gem](https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable) to clone an entry with some associations. Here is my action

```
def copy
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @newgroup = Group.new(@group.dup :include => :lessons).save
    redirect_to @newgroup
end
```

And that's what I get when trying to do it:

```
 undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Group name: "40-201B",
 created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

How can I fix it or do what I need the other way around?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need to combine new and dup the way you are... try

```
@newgroup = @group.dup(:include => :lessons).save
```

You should also consider some logic to confirm the item is valid and was actually saved before you redirect.

Comment: @Euphe Glad I could help, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted to close the question.